# How to return success function of ajax to php variable

Tags: php, ajax

I want to save returned data from success function of ajax to a PHP variable.
Instead of saving data to `'#showThis'` I want to save it in a PHP variable.  This is my code.

```
 function getId(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/feeController/test',
        data: {studentId: id},
        type: 'post',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#showThis").html(data);
        }
    });       
}
```

Comment: I dont think you understand how AJAX and PHP work together. PHP is server side. ajax is client side. ajax cannot create or use php variables, it can only make calls to php services. PHP can only inject values into javascript _before the script is sent to the client_

Comment: php is processed first. then page is delivered. then javascript is executed. you cannot pass from JS to PHP.

Comment: You should probably set the PHP variable on the feeController/test code, then return a feedback message to finish your AJAX call

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Javascript is not able to write to a PHP variable.

You could send another ajax call to a php file, and simply save those variables sent by javascript in the PHP file itself. However, you cannot write directly from javascript to php without ajax.